# Formated drive is not fully empty

Tags: partition, hard-disk, gparted

I used Gparted to delete the partitions on a HDD as for some reason had used data on it however, after restarting my system it says my unallocated 4TB drive is only 3.64TB.

Answer (score 2):

3.64 TiB is 4 TB.

The drive is 4 TB big, i.e 4*1000^4 bytes.  This is the same as 3.63798*1024^4 bytes, or approximately 3.64 TiB.

Disk manufacturers use GB and TB (metric) when writing their sizes.  Many software applications, including `gparted`, use GiB and TiB (binary) instead, due to tradition.

Related:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tebibyte

Comment: Ah so I'm just stupid and didn't notice TiB, thanks.